# Simplifying a proof statement.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Trying to simplify a the following equation:

Prove that if ***n*** is an **even** integer and ***m*** an an **odd** integer, then ***$(n + 2)^2 - (m - 1)^2$*** is **even**

So this is what I have so far:

If ***n*** is an integer
      then ***n = 2k*** where ***k*** is some integer and
     ***m = 2j + 1*** where ***j*** is some integer.
Then: ***$(2k + 2)^2 - (2j + 1-1)^2$*** 
     =***$(2k + 2)^2 - (2j)^2$***

I really need to get the expression down to ***2(..)*** where ***(..)*** is some integer to prove the statement.

Comment: Did you try expanding the terms that you've found?

Comment: $(2k + 2)^2 - (2j)^2 = 2^2*(k+1)^2 - 2^2j^2 = 2^2((k+1)^2 -j^2) = 2*2((k+1)^2 -j^j)$.

Comment: Square of an even integer is an even integer, and difference of two even integer is also even. Hence Proved.

Comment: Thanks guys that is an enormous help to me.

Answer (score 3):

You are so close:

$(2k+2)^2−(2j)^2\\
4[(k+1)^2 - j^2]$

Comment: Wonderful! Seems obvious now that I look at it :/

Answer (score 0):

From $(2k+2)^2-(2j)^2$ we can expand to get $4k^2+8k+4-4j^2$.

Next, we simply factor a bit to get $4(k^2-j^2+2k+1)$.

I'll leave the rest up to you ;)